# Python Pandas: Hlookup Function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I may be overthinking this. But I am trying to lookup a value from another df when it matches certain criteria. This is an example of the first DF:

```
City  A  B  C  D
BKN   5  2  3  5
DET   4  1  6  4
WAS   3  2  3  7
```

And here is the second:

```
Name  Cri  City  Wanted Val  
P1    B    BKN       ?
P2    D    DET       ?
```

Hopefully this makes sense how I have it, but essentially I want my 'Wanted Val' column to be filled with whats at the coordinates for Cri and City. So the final result would end up being, for P1, a 2 in the wanted val, and for P2 a 4, and so on. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

```
In [3010]: df1
Out[3010]:
  City  A  B  C  D
0  BKN  5  2  3  5
1  DET  4  1  6  4
2  WAS  3  2  3  7

In [3011]: df2
Out[3011]:
  Name Cri City
0   P1   B  BKN
1   P2   D  DET

In [3012]: df2['Wanted-Val'] = df1.set_index('City').lookup(df2.City, df2.Cri)

In [3013]: df2
Out[3013]:
  Name Cri City  Wanted-Val
0   P1   B  BKN           2
1   P2   D  DET           4
```

Comment: You win for the speed ~ :-)

Comment: Ah, that was close. :D

Comment: Haha wow 2 responses within seconds of each other. Thank you guys! I just didnt have the index set properly.. Yikes! Thanks again will accept answer once it allows me :)

Comment: is this still a valid answer?