# Is there a VLOOKUP function in Python that allows you to return a value from a column based on value in original table?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I have started to learn Python as I am interested in using it for a lot of data analysis that I currently do in excel.

I work in logistics and one very common activity I currently perform in excel is to lookup a transport tariff and apply the cost to delivery data.

Below is a very simple DataFrame of deliveries:

[Deliveries DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7DaB.png)

Below is a simple DataFrame of the tariffs:

[Tariff DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ock4I.png)

In excel I would add a volume band column and then lookup the zip code in the tariffs table and return the column number based on the volume band column.

I have managed to achieve the same result using the code below but I feel as though there may be a better method to achieve these results. If anyone has a better way of performing this action I would be very grateful for some advice.

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzgqY.png)

Comment: Could you copy/paste the code and data here, rather than sharing it through photos? It makes it much easier for people to actually run the code themselves :) While I will be looking at the entirety of your code later, I must mention that using `iterrows` is probably a bad idea, for numerous reasons. Luckily, there exists a great alternative called `itertuples`, which, even on small examples, is about 1000 times faster than `iterrows`.

Comment: Oops I forgot to link to [mcve].

Comment: Check pandas lookup https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I will add the code into the question in future rather than as an image. This was my first time and I thought the images would embed into the display. I have tried the itertuples and got this working, but timing this vs iterrows the speed is showing as virtually the same so doesn't seem any performance improvements. I've had a look at the 'lookup' documentation but can't seem to work out how to get this working, keeps coming back with errors.

Comment: hi -- try keeping your 2 step process; for the second step see my proposed approach below with `.merge`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the replies. In particular the suggestion of using the lookup function. With the assistance of [Python Pandas: Hlookup Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46774241/python-pandas-hlookup-function) I managed to get the lookup function working.

I had to make a few modifications to my data as below:

1. I changed the column labels of the tariff table to be integer numbers so that they column labels matched the value being applied to the 'bands' column.
2. When loading the bands csv I have set the 'Band' column to be a string instead of integer.

This has then allowed me to perform the lookup function. Before it was failing as Python couldn't match due to the mismatch of data types.

I have now performed the lookup using this one simple line of code and it seems to run between 3 to 4 times faster than the iterrows and itertuples functions:

```
data_banded['Cost'] = tariff_V2.set_index('Zip').lookup(data_banded.Zip, data_banded.Band)
```

Below is full details of code to get this working:

```
# Create sample DataFrames (data = delivery information, bands = lookup volume band, tariff = lookup cost by band):
data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Customer', 'Zip', 'Volume'], 
                    data = [['A', 'RG', 0.7], ['B', 'KT', 1.3], ['C', 'NN', 1.8], ['D', 'PO', 2.4]])
bands = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Volume', 'Band'], 
                    data = [[0.5, '1'], [1, '2'], [1.5, '3'], [2, '4'], [2.5, '5']])
tariff = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Zip', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 
                    data = [['RG', 10, 20, 30, 40, 50], ['KT', 12, 24, 36, 48, 60],
                            ['NN', 14, 28, 42, 56, 70], ['PO', 16, 32, 48, 64, 80]])

# Create DataFrame that has delivery data and the respective volume band each line falls into:
data_banded = pd.merge_asof(data, bands, on = 'Volume', direction = 'forward')

# Lookup the cost from the tariff table and apply to a new column called 'Cost' in the delivery data:
data_banded['Cost'] = tariff.set_index('Zip').lookup(data_banded['Zip'], data_banded['Band'])
```

Thanks again to everyone for your help and support.

Regards
Mike

Comment: Hey, can you share more data/code? I think a even better solution can be found. I'm taking a look at it right now.

Comment: Hi Alexander, sorry, I had goner to sleep last night. I have now revised my answer above to include some code that creates DataFrames and runs the solution using lookup. It will be interesting to see if you have a better solution to this. Cheers, Mikee,.

Comment: No worries, I started typing up an answer but ended up going to bed before finishing it ;) I’ll take a look at your code and share it in a few hours!

Answer (score -1):

For the first step, to classify each row by which band it should be, you seem to be doing the "right thing" already with `pd.merge_asof`. I don't have a better idea :-)

Second step -- to get the tariff for each band, you should look at using `df.merge` or `df.join` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html -- each time you are doing a vlookup, you are essentially joining the two tables based on a key.

So in your case, do something like `df_merged = data_banded.merge(tariffs, left_on=['Zip', 'Band'], right_on=['Zip', 'Band'], how='left')` -- this assumes your tariff table has zip-specific values. If it's just by Band, delete 'Zip' from the lists.

Comment: Doesn’t merging mean that “keys” must be unique, or am I confusing this with something else?

Comment: Oh you're right! I wasn't reading closely, there has to logic to put each row into the right band. Let me edit my answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Yeah, I was originally looking at the df.merge function but couldn't see how to return varying columns based on the band number of each row.

Comment: Original poster had solved that part already; see use of `merge_asof` here at top of pic https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzgqY.png